# Why is my steady state output different from Coursera's solution?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

I'm taking a Computational Neuroscience class on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/computational-neuroscience/) and am stuck on one of the quiz problems.

The question is framed as the following:

> Suppose that we had a linear recurrent network of 5 input nodes and 5 output nodes. Let us say that our network's weight matrix W is:
>
> ```
> W = [0.6 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1]
>     [0.1 0.6 0.1 0.1 0.1]
>     [0.1 0.1 0.6 0.1 0.1]
>     [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.6 0.1]
>     [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.6]
> ```
>
> (Essentially, all 0.1, besides 0.6 on the diagonals.)
>
> Suppose that we have a static input vector u:
>
> ```
> u = [0.6]
>     [0.5]
>     [0.6]
>     [0.2]
>     [0.1]
> ```
>
> Finally, suppose that we have a recurrent weight matrix M:
>
> ```
> M = [-0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0]
>     [0, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.25]
>     [0.25, 0, -0.25, 0, 0.25]
>     [0.25, 0.25, 0, -0.25, 0]
>     [0, 0.25, 0.25, 0, -0.25]
> ```
>
> Which of the following is the steady state output v_ss of the network?
> (Hint: See the lecture on recurrent networks, and consider writing some Octave or Matlab code to handle the eigenvectors/values (you may use the "eig" function))'

**The notes for the class can be found [here](https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/_19b2cf740de5dc223e1ad6e8978b4acf_Suppl-Mat-Recurrent-Networks.pdf?Expires=1483747200&Signature=O7ioJ76sx9SKvvFUJUaxukab4EYD-ADsopZKCnIWreLEO0Swyw54fZnXOCgRxdgyHZrbDxuUvV-41j9Bx7HSABhO4-d3z1cfELBdIg25L8jUSNDtGZsLv6uMHl4dIf%7E2mHPPfK9YRvk3MF-wXLUAyzwbUKteS59c6mQyGT8kgAk_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A). Specifically, the equation for the steady state formula can be found on slides 5 and 6.**

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

# Construct W, the network weight matrix
W = np.ones((5,5))
W = W / 10.
np.fill_diagonal(W, 0.6)
# Construct u, the static input vector
u = np.zeros(5)
u[0] = 0.6
u[1] = 0.5
u[2] = 0.6
u[3] = 0.2
u[4] = 0.1
# Connstruct M, the recurrent weight matrix
M = np.zeros((5,5))
np.fill_diagonal(M, -0.25)
for i in range(3):
    M[2+i][i] = 0.25
    M[i][2+i] = 0.25
for i in range(2):
    M[3+i][i] = 0.25
    M[i][3+i] = 0.25

# We need to matrix multiply W and u together to get h
# NOTE: cannot use W * u, that's going to do a scalar multiply
# it's element wise otherwise
h = W.dot(u)
print 'This is h' 
print h

# Ok then the big deal is:
#                               h dot e_i
# v_ss = sum_(over all eigens) ------------ e_i
#                               1 - lambda_i

eigs = np.linalg.eig(M)

eigenvalues = eigs[0]
eigenvectors = eigs[1]

v_ss = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(5):
    v_ss += (np.dot(h,eigenvectors[:, i]))/((1.0-eigenvalues[i])) * eigenvectors[:,i]
print 'This is our steady state v_ss'
print v_ss
```

The correct answer is:

```
[0.616, 0.540, 0.609, 0.471, 0.430]
```

This is what I am getting:

```
This is our steady state v_ss
[ 0.64362264  0.5606784   0.56007018  0.50057043  0.40172501]
```

Why is my output different, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution with my matrices:

```
W = np.array([[0.6 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1],
                [0.1 , 0.6 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1],
                [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.6 , 0.1 , 0.1],
                [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.6 , 0.1],
                [0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.6]])
u = np.array([.6, .5, .6, .2, .1])

M = np.array([[-0.75 , 0 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0],
                [0 , -0.75 , 0 , 0.75 , 0.75],
                [0.75 , 0 , -0.75 , 0 , 0.75],
                [0.75 , 0.75 , 0.0 , -0.75 , 0],
                [0 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0 , -0.75]])
```

and your code generated the right solution:

```
This is h
[ 0.5   0.45  0.5   0.3   0.25]
This is our steady state v_ss
[ 1.663354    1.5762684   1.66344153  1.56488258  1.53205348]
```

Maybe the problem is with the Test on coursera. Have you tried to contact them on the forum?

Comment: I didn't know who to contact. You're confident in my program to answer this correctly? I doubt Coursera would put the wrong solution out for a bunch of people. I feel like my code must have a bug or I must have a flaw in the logic.